# Keras - Glorot uniform initializer: input and output unit?

Tags: python, keras

there are several thing that i do not understand in Keras documentation

> It draws samples from a uniform distribution within `-limit, limit`
>   where limit is `sqrt(6 / (fan_in + fan_out))` where `fan_in` is the
>   number of input units in the weight tensor and `fan_out` is the number
>   of output units in the weight tensor.

Where i can see the `fan_in` and `fan_out` of my model?
This is my model:

> ```
> model = Sequential()
> model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(224,224,3)))
> model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
> model.add(Dropout(0.5))
> model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `model.summary()`, there you will see `input` and `output` shapes of each layer, that's what **Glorot uniform initializer** uses for `fan_in` and `fan_out` respectively.

**Your example**:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
flatten_1 (Flatten)           (None, 150528)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 256)               38535424  
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 257       
=================================================================
```

So `dense_1` will have `fan_in` equal to 150528 (it's input) and `fan_out` of 256 (it's output). `dense_2` on the other hand will have `fan_in` 256 (input from previous dense layer) and `fan_out` 1 (it's output shape).

Comment: What i got only Layer (type), Output Shape, and Param

Comment: @sekti92uk See description of your example output, does that help?

Comment: where is param comes on `dense_1` comes from? 
if i calculate `150528*256 = 38,535,168`. Why the result is `38535424`?

Comment: 256 biases are added, but that's beside the point, do you understand what is `fan_in` and `fan_out`?

Comment: oh i forgot 256 bias. yes, i am clearly understand now. Thanks.